# Dynamically create submenupages OOP style

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm redoing a page builder so that it's written in OOP style. This is practical, because I don't need to write bunch of code for every settings page, but just specify parameters and let it build itself.

So I created a class, defined my constructors, and started building, but I hit a snag. The class is below:

```
class SettingsSubageBuilder {

    private $subpage_name;

    private $html_array;

    public function __construct( $subpage_name, $html_array ) {
        $this->subpage_name = $subpage_name;
        $this->html_array   = $html_array;
    }

    public function create_submenu_pages() {
        $page_hook = 'mytheme_theme' . strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $this->subpage_name ) );

        add_submenu_page( 'theme_settings', $this->subpage_name, $this->subpage_name, 'edit_theme_options', $page_hook, 'mytheme_'.strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $this->subpage_name ) ).'_render_page' );
    }

    public function mytheme_'.strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $this->subpage_name ) ).'_render_page() {

    }
}
```

Now adding [submenu pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) seems easy. But there is an issue of the callable function.

Say I name my submenu page 'Header Settings'.

The `$page_hook` will be `mytheme_theme_header_settings`, and the callable function will be `mytheme_header_settings_render_page`.

Now when trying to create the callable function, I have a problem obviously. The

```
public function mytheme_'.strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $this->subpage_name ) ).'_render_page() {

    }
```

won't work - I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.strtolower( str_replace( '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting '(' in /theme-settings/theme-settings.php on line 138

So how can I create methods that depend on the constructor in php?

Comment: You don't need to dynamically create a function name here. If you keep everything inside the object (referring to the variables and functions with `$this`) every instance is isolated from other instances.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, I can just create function called `render_page` and no matter when I create separate instances of this object, they will render independently of each other? There won't be clashing in the `add_submenu_page()` function?

Comment: That is correct. If you want your instances to share variable values you have to explicitly declare them as static.

Comment: I realized what I needed to do, just a bit of self referencing and it all worked out. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__call` magic method to catch any method calls to methods you have not explicitly defined. This way you can listen to the corresponding function based on the content of the variable.

```
class SettingsSubageBuilder {
    /* Other code */    


    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
           if ($name == 'mytheme_'.strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $this->subpage_name ) ).'_render_page') {
                //Do stuff
            } else {
                  throw new Exception("Call to undefined method $name");
            }
    }
}
```

Manual page : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call